# why Android fetch declared fields of a class disordeded?

Tags: java, android, reflection, field

Suppose we have this class

**Animal.java**

```
public class Animal {
    private String name;
    private String owner;
    private String breed;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Field f : Animal.class.getDeclaredFields()){
        sb.append(f.getName()).append(", ");
    }

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Why the TextView gives me the fields with not the declared order?(name, owner, breed)
The output is: breed, name, owner

Comment: I've ran into this as well.  Isn't android lovely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Android documentation is not complete regarding to this method. [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) mentions the following:

> The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any
>   particular order.

Looks like there's no exact JVM specification on how fields are stored in memory / cached. However, You always can check [Android Class source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#Class.privateGetDeclaredFields%28boolean%29) to get insight about exact fields order (but it can be different from version to version).

Comment: Yes but, "regular" Java, with a main class, gives the output ordered by line number.. I dont know why....

Comment: Could it be just some jvm implementation specific? Anyway, we shouldn't rely on not documented staff, because it most probably will lead to issues with further code support.